# How does Brexit affect English Law?

Tags: law, united-kingdom, brexit

I ask only about the law of England and Wales, and not of Scotland or Ireland.
I ask a related question on [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/11167/89).

I know that  [the ECHR will continue to possess jurisdiction over the UK](http://www.freshfields.com/en/global/Britain_and_the_EU/Your_human_rights/), but probably not the ECJ.

Comment: What parts of English law are you particularly interested in? There's lots of ways Brexit will affect English law.

Comment: This seems like it's too broad to be answerable in SE format. You should restrict the question significcantly to be better answerable

Comment: Generally speaking, EU regulations, and domestic legislation derived from EU directives, apply to the whole of the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much (at least immediately).

The process in the EU is that, when a directive is issued, states must modify their laws to comply with that directive. If a state fails to comply, someone affected by that negative will first try the issue in the national tribunals and (if those do not agree with the plaintiff), then the subject may recourse to the ECJ. If the ECJ states that national law is in contradiction with the directives, then it can fine the state until the law is modified.

In that sense, there will be no legal void. Laws created/altered because of EU directives will be still British laws because they were approved by the Parliament of the UK; the main difference is that after Brexit the Parliament will be able to ignore EU directives when creating new laws and changing the existing ones.